# Init angular module value or factory from $.ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I implement AngularJS into project.

```
angular.module('xmpl.service', []).
     value('objProduct', {
          productName: 'ASUS', // this fiel name and value set on angular start!!!!
          price: 0,            // this fiel name and value set on angular start!!!!
          func1: function (setObjProduct) {            
               this.productName = setObjProduct.productName;
               this.price = setObjProduct.price;                           
          },
          func2: function (name) {
               return this.productName + ' ' + name + '.';
          }
     }).
     value('objCustomer', {
          info: function (name) {
               this.name = name;
          }
     });
...
var myApp = angular.module('xmpl', ['xmpl.service', 'xmpl.directive', 'xmpl.filter']).
     run(function (objProduct, objCustomer) {            
            // I hope $.json request to MVC Controller in project will be here
            // Object from response go to func1 or func2

            // Some test object
            var newObjProduct = {
                productName: 'SAMSUNG',
                price: 400
            };            
            objProduct.func1(newObjProduct);
        });    

function XmplController($scope, objProduct, objCustomer) {                
        $scope.greeting = function (value) {
            return objCustomer.name + ' ' + value + ' ' + objProduct.productName;
        }

        $scope.varTest1 = objProduct.productName;

        $scope.varFuncTest = function () {
            return objProduct.price;            
        }        
    }
```

I try to send $.ajax request to MVC Controller and get some object from response. There any way to set fields from response object and set there names and values instead of 'productName' and 'price'. In BLL all object can be change, and I try to get some object from $.ajax response and set it structure to the angular. How I Should change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
func1: function (setObjProduct) {
       for (var property in setObjProduct) {
           if (setObjProduct.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
               this[property] = setObjProduct[property];
           }
       }
   }
```

This is standard javascript, there is nothing specific to angular.